# DocuSign REST API Remove EnvelopeID from PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the REST API to submit documents for InPerson signing from my website. When the documents are completed signing, Docusign inserts the EnvelopeID at the top of the resulting PDF document. This results in the EnvelopeID covering critical document information. We need to REMOVE this envelopeID from the document, or at the very least move to the bottom of the page.  Our account has the "Envelope ID Stamp Control" feature enabled and it is selected on the Preferences|Features page, but the EvnelopeID continues to appear at the top of the finished PDF.  I have been unable to locate articles on how to implement this feature via REST API.  What Envelope settings need to be submitted in order for us to suppress the EnvelopeID stamp on the finished PDF?
Many Thanks in Advance
ward

Comment: Docusign doesn't seem to document anything using their API when they could instead show you how to use it in a UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Envelope including the Envelope ID on the Document" feature in Settings >> Sending Settings gives you the ability to set the *Default* ID stamp behavior (enable or disable) for Envelopes that are sent via the account.  If you NEVER want ID stamped on any of the envelopes sent via the account, then click the "Envelope ID stamp control" link, uncheck "Include Envelope ID by Default" and Save.

Additionally, even if the ID Stamp is enabled at the account level (i.e., "Include Envelope ID by Default" is selected in Settings >> Sending Settings >> Enable including the Envelope ID on the document), you can still override this setting for each individual envelope you send.  Via the REST API, you should be able to do so in the API request to Create the Envelope (POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes), by setting the **envelopeIdStamping** property to false -- to prevent the stamp from being added for the envelope being sent.

Comment: One thing I'll add from my testing, if you have envelope stamping turned off in the Console and you create a new envelope but apply a template to it that was created when you had stamping turned on in your account, then the stamp will go into that envelope.  You would need to re-create that template for it to accurately reflect your updated account settings.  Just FYI

Comment: That exact parameter is failing for me. which is disappointing.