# how to get "envelope ID" displayed in the bottom corner in docusign completed Document

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to understand if it would be possible to display the "Envelope ID" generated on the final PDF to be displayed in the bottom corner of the page instead of top corner.

The issue i am facing it the display is cutting of the LOGO of the page.

Any reference would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to control the placement (location) of the Envelope ID stamp that DocuSign automatically places on the documents -- but you can disable (remove) it altogether.  See the answer in this post for information on how that's done:  [DocuSign REST API Remove EnvelopeID from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403407/docusign-rest-api-remove-envelopeid-from-pdf/19407445#19407445).

Once you disable DocuSign's auto-stamping of the Envelope ID, you can use the **Envelope ID** tab to place the Envelope ID whereever you want it to appear in the Envelope. Simply specify the Envelope ID tabs as part of your Create Envelope request:

```
"envelopeIdTabs": [{ 
 "anchorString": null, 
 "anchorXOffset": null, 
 "anchorYOffset": null, 
 "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": null, 
 "anchorUnits": null, 
 "documentId": "#", 
 "pageNumber": "#", 
 "xPosition": "#", 
 "yPosition": "#", 
 "tabLabel": "Envelope ID, 
}]
```

See page 352 of the REST API guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) for details about the Envelope ID tab type.

Comment: (Updated answer to add info about using the Envelope ID tab type to place the Envelope ID whereever you want.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403407/docusign-rest-api-remove-envelopeid-from-pdf/19407445#19407445 -  I followed the instructions. But i do not see the option as mentioned in the post. Is it something I have ask administrator to enable for my account?

Comment: Yes, the "Envelope ID Stamp Control" feature has to be enabled for your DocuSign account by DocuSign before you'll see that option in Preferences >> Features. Also, I suspect that they may need to specifically enable the "Envelope ID" tag type for your account as well.