# Remove or hide the DocuSign envelope ID tag from a downloaded attachment document

Tags: attachment, document, docusignapi, envelope

Related to;
[how to get "envelope ID" displayed in the bottom corner in docusign completed Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771435/how-to-get-envelope-id-displayed-in-the-bottom-corner-in-docusign-completed-do)

I desire to keep the Envelope ID tag on the signed document

Comment: I'm confused, your subject states "Remove or hide envelope tag" however your question in your post is "I desire to keep the envelope tag".  Which one is it?

Comment: I want to maintain the envelope ID on the signed document and hide or remove the envelope ID on the attached document

Comment: See this previous post for how to enable/disable envelope stamping:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403407/docusign-rest-api-remove-envelopeid-from-pdf

Answer (score 2):

The *Envelope ID Stamp Control* feature in **Preferences** >> **Features** gives you the ability to set the Default ID stamp behavior (enable or disable) for Envelopes that are sent via the account. If you NEVER want ID stamped on any of the envelopes sent via the account, then click the "Envelope ID stamp control" link, select "Remove Stamps" and Save.

Additionally, even if the ID Stamp is enabled at the account level (i.e., "Stamp Pages" is selected in **Preferences** >> **Features** >> **Envelope ID Stamp Control**), you can still override this setting for each individual envelope you send. Via the REST API, you should be able to do so in the API request to Create the Envelope (POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes), by setting the `envelopeIdStamping` property to false -- to prevent the stamp from being added for the envelope being sent.

---

**UPDATE**

DocuSign has since released a new UI for their Website App, to access the above features you may need to switch back to the Classic View from your Account Preferences.