# Unable to hide envelope_id from Document - DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

**Prerequisites:** Hide envelope *via API*.

Error:

> (400) Reason: Bad Request Trace-Token: 52331e18-55c5-4801-8c55-c6e4fd4a5712 Timestamp: Thu, 02 Mar 2023 13:19:06 GMT HTTP response headers:
> HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '164', 'Content-Type': application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff','X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '52331e18-55c5-4801-8c55-c6e4fd4a5712', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA5DFE181', 'Date': 'Thu, 02 Mar 2023 13:19:06 GMT', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'})
> HTTP response body: b'{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Boolean value expected for parameter: envelopeIdStamping"}'

I've checked this answer: [Remove or hide the DocuSign envelope ID tag from a downloaded attachment document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354279/remove-or-hide-the-docusign-envelope-id-tag-from-a-downloaded-attachment-documen) but it's not working for me.

**Code snippet:**

> envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
> email_subject="Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK",
> template_id=template_id,
> template_roles=[signer],
> status="sent",
> envelope_id_stamping=False,
> )

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it a string with the word "false" lower case:

```
envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition( email_subject="Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK", template_id=template_id, template_roles=[signer], status="sent", envelope_id_stamping="false", )
```