# DocusignAPI : How can I download the internal document out of envelope without the envelope_id automatic stamp?

Tags: docusignapi

I have DocuSign documents (.pdf extension documents that were signed by docusign). I'm trying to find a programmatic solution via DocuSign API how can I remove the "DocuSign Envelope ID: {GUID}" automatic stamp that exists on every top of page in the documents.

1. Is there such a solution inside DocuSign API? and if yes, how can it be done?
2. If not, what are the alternatives?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it addressed your question. Post additional information or a new question if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

For new envelopes, you can set the **envelopeIdStamping** property in your [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request so that the stamp is not included. The stamp cannot be removed on completed envelopes.

```
{
 "envelopeIdStamping" : "false",    
 "status": "sent",
 "emailSubject": "Example of one recipient, type signer",
 "documents": [],
 "recipients": {}
}
```

Note that envelopeIdStamping is driven based on Account and Admin settings.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19407445/1219543) for more information.
See this [page](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-envelope-id) for other options.