# Docusign envelopeIdStamping doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: docusignapi

Very similar to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403407/docusign-rest-api-remove-envelopeid-from-pdf/19407445#19407445)

I have envelopes I'm sending out using the API. In our development account there seems to be nothing I can do to stop the docusign envelope id from being stamped onto the document.

According to the API explorer (and the dude who answered the similar question) the field I'm supposed to use is `envelopeIdStamping` 
Here I am using it as "false" (because everything is a string), but still getting envelope IDs stamped all over my document.

```
{
  "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "cc728837-af2e-41d0-b696-5b5467d3f986",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "email@domain.tld",
      "name": "First Last",
      "roleName": "Role"
    }
  ]
}
```

That call created my envelope `7d3b98e3-0897-4ec1-a12f-e3ad301616a9` which you can see is still getting stamped. 
[image: the thing i explicitly asked not to get.]

for fun, I've also tried to use the python sdk to get around it. 
`envelope_definition.envelope_id_stamping = "false"`
or sending `"true"` across the wire in case it's a bizarro parameter. 
i've also just tried `false` in json or `False` in Python.

These IDs keep coming, no matter what I do. Send help.

Comment: Are you able to inactive the stamping in the account level and not by including the tag in your API call? Do you see the option in the admin console?

Answer (score 0):

this feature is only available on the account level. Meaning, you can control for ALL envelopes if they're stamped or not, you cannot do that for a specific envelope.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this using postman and it works as expected when adding the property `"envelopeIdStamping":"false"` there is no envelope id stamping on the document.

First, you have to make sure that you remove the checked **"include envelope id by default"**

[Example of configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGd0F.png)