# Docusign Rest API envolopeIdStamping

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently using the rest API for Docusign.
I want to send the envelope without having the Id stamped on my documents.

So in the envelopeDefinition,I have put the parameter envelopeIdStamping to "false" as said in the API documentation.

But it's not working,

So I have checked, and there is one subject saying that it should work:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403407/docusign-rest-api-remove-envelopeid-from-pdf/19407445#19407445)
and some other saying that it should not work if the configuration at account level is wrong : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066725/docusign-envelopeidstamping-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything)

Can someone provide me with a complete response concerning this topic?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be enabled for your account by DocuSign. 
Please send your demo account id to go-live [at sign] docusign.com and ask for the feature to be enabled.